# hbase 0.90.5 not started in distributed mode with hadoop 1.0

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I can't start HMaster :(
Please help me. Second day about this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Regionserver: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer

Unable to start master
```

Has already worked well hadoop cluster installation. Wait 30 sec before start hbase.

I followed this tutorial http://hbase.apache.org/book/example_config.html#d0e2432
Change system configuration in required section ulimit and nproc

Have: 1 master, 4 slaves

Here all diagnostic information

```
Java java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
Debian 6.03 Linux slave1 2.6.32-5-amd64

Copy hadoop-core to hbase/lib on each machine
hduser@slave1:/usr/local/hbase$ ls lib/hadoo*
lib/hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar

Hbase: hbase-0.90.5
```

DETAILED CONFIGURATION HERE http://pastie.org/private/hnhpw2jeq7p2njegnuha 
(unable to put here - cause 2 links limit)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If yes,please share the solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can also copy commons-configuration-1.6.jar in the hadoop lib directory to the hbase lib directory and try agai

Answer (score 0):

There must be more errors or warning before this error.
Clear the /hbase/logs dir, then start_hbase.sh and provide full log here

Answer (score 0):

make your hosts file as following:

127.0.0.1 localhost

For Hadoop
192.168.56.1 master

192.168.56.101 slave

and in hbase conf put following entries :

hbase.rootdir
hdfs://master:9000/hbase


hbase.master
master:60000
The host and port that the HBase master runs at.


hbase.regionserver.port
60020
The host and port that the HBase master runs at.

hbase.cluster.distributed
true


hbase.tmp.dir
/home/cluster/Hadoop/hbase-0.90.4/temp


hbase.zookeeper.quorum
master


dfs.replication
2


hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort
2181
Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
The port at which the clients will connect.


If you are using localhost anywhere remove that and replace it with "master" which is name for namenode in your hostfile....

one morething you can do

sudo gedit /etc/hostname

this will open the hostname file bydefault ubuntu will be there so make it master. and restart your system.

For hbase specify in "regionserver" file inside conf dir put these entries

master

slave

and restart.everything.